# Is pid really unique

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, kernel, pid

Is there a case where PID does not end up being unique? Is it the best way to identify a process (or a thread)? I read that previous versions of Linux had a different approach

Thanks

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Maybe the question has been reworded and the 'not constructive' status is no longer relevant? This question was the first hit in a web search, and the answers are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

PIDs can take about 32k values (`sysctl kernel.pid_max` can change it), so they are reused quickly enough. pid + start time may be better. systemd attaches per-process information on extended attributes in cgroupfs (procfs would also work) to avoid the ambiguity of a pid->attr mapping.

Threads and processes share the same namespace (you can see it in `/proc/<pid>/task/<taskid>`), with `<pid>` = `<taskid>` for the process' initial thread. Pid namespaces limit the list of visible pids, but they don't introduce any overlap; pids and task ids remain unique while their owner is running.

Comment: PIDs are not reused while still in use, though.

Comment: Absolutely. I answered based on one reading of the question, and I hope the asker will clarify.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about the `getpid()` system call then yes, PID is unique per process. *Except*, that is, if you are using threads on older versions of the Linux kernel.  Then each thread may have its own process-id.

To quote from [this discussion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/pthread-problem-65271/):

> Kernel 2.4.20 uses [NPTL (Native posix thread library)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) and this is the kernel shipped with RH9. RH8 uses Kernel 2.4.18 which doesn't implement NPTL (Meaning each thread gets its own PID and therefore a good description of it's status in /proc). NPTL is a "real" implementation of POSIX threads meaning that the threads share alot more including the PID. It is more efficient way of running threads for a couple of reasons, however, I don't know of any easy tricks to debug these kind of threads. How do you know when your thread is sleeping versus waiting on a semaphore, or which threads have died in a process with lots of threads, etc.

From the [wikipedia link on NPTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library):

> NPTL has been part of Red Hat Enterprise Linux since version 3, and in the Linux kernel since version 2.6. It is now a fully integrated part of the GNU C Library.[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library)

Under the covers even the 2.6.X kernels have a virtual-process for threads.  You can see the thread process-ids with `ps auxf`:

```
root      2501  0.0  0.3 244448 25576 ?    Ss   Jul03   0:11 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2716  0.0  0.5 384776 46696 ?    S    Oct14   0:17  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2717  0.0  0.5 382208 44304 ?    S    Oct14   0:11  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
```

The following program spits out the same pid for both main and thread under Linux kernel  2.6.18.   The self id returned from `pthread_self()` identifies the thread uniquely.

```
#include <pthread.h>
void foo() {
  printf("thread: pid = %d, self = %ld\n", getpid(), pthread_self());
}
main() {
  pthread_t thread;
  printf("main: pid = %d, self = %ld\n", getpid(), pthread_self());
  pthread_create(&thread, 0L, foo, 0L);
  pthread_join(thread, 0L);
}
```

The output is:

```
main: pid = 13246, self = 46912496175248
thread: pid = 13246, self = 1084229952
```

Comment: So recent versions of Linux would have the same PID for processes and their threads? What would be the unique identifier for a thread in this case? T[G]ID?

Comment: I'd use `pthread_self();` @Buffalo.  I've changed my answer to show its output.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing unique about pthread_self(). The returned value is just a pointer to pthread_t (it is not an integer!) so it can appear in multiple processes.

Comment: `pthread_self()` can be called in multiple processes but it will be unique value for the the thread because they are all in the same memory space so the address is unique @LubosD.

Comment: Yes, but being just a memory pointer, it has a potential of being recycled even faster than pid/tid.

Comment: Huh?  It won't be "recycled" until the thread goes away.  And god help you if you are still using the thread pointer after it has been reused @LubosD.

Comment: Yeah and that's the problem. If one thread is joined and a new one is created, with the same pthread_t, then you cannot distinguish the old (dead) thread and the new one. pthread_t is a unique identification ONLY at one given point in time and only in one memory space.